# Postgres - constraint violation, by rows that don't exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add a constraint to a table

```
ALTER TABLE myTable_202211 ADD CONSTRAINT const_202211 
CHECK ( loadedTime >= DATE '2022-Nov-01' AND loadedTime < '2022-Nov-08')
```

but am getting this error....

```
ERROR:  check constraint "const_202211" of relation "mytable_202211" is violated by some row
SQL state: 23514
```

At first glance it looks like my data is must be outside the correct range, but if I select the min and max loadedTime I see....

```
select min(loadedTime), max(LoadedTime) from myTable_202211;
--"2022-11-01 00:05:17", "2022-11-06 23:56:00"
```

Or in other words, the data appears to be well within the range specified by the constraint.

As a double check I also tried deleting any records that might be out of range.

```
delete from myTable_202211 WHERE loadedTime >'2022-11-06 23:56:00'
delete from myTable_202211 WHERE loadedTime <'2022-11-01 00:00:01'
```

Both queries deleted zero rows.

So, it looks like my constraint is being violated by rows that don't appear to exist - which doesn't make sense - what should my next step be?

UPDATE
The query proposed by ypercube returns "Succesfully run. total query runtime  17ms. Zero rows affected.". `LoadedTime` is `timestamp without timezone`

I'm tending towards a memory corruption issue. Attempting a

```
VACUUM FULL myTable;
```

returns

```
ERROR:  row is too big: size 18464, maximum size 8160 SQL state: 54000
```

Which I've had before, I though I had fixed (for at least a few months) by replacing a lot of very expensive memory.

Create table script was

```
CREATE TABLE myTable_202211 (
  MessID          BIGSERIAL ,
  rawMessage      CHAR(250),               
  loadedTime      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL     
  )
PARTITION BY RANGE (loadedTime);
```

Comment: did you try to see if this returns any rows?: `SELECT * FROM myTable_202211 WHERE NOT (loadedTime >= DATE '2022-Nov-01' AND loadedTime < '2022-Nov-08') ;`

Comment: What is the datatype of `loadedTime`? It would be best if you added the `CREATE TABLE` in the question.

Comment: My guess is that the type is timestamp or timestamp_tz and the conversion from date (you use date literals in the constraint) is the cause. You must have some timestamps that are out of the constraint range, due to to timezone offset.

Comment: I've just noticed that the second literal is not a DATE - and we can't know if that's what you used in the constraint/queries or just typo when posting here. You should try to be consistent and even better use literals of same datatype as the columns. What happens if you try this?: `ALTER TABLE myTable_202211 ADD CONSTRAINT const_202211 
CHECK ( loadedTime >= '2022-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND loadedTime < '2022-11-08'::timestamp)  ;`

Comment: Also what does this return?: `SELECT * FROM myTable_202211  WHERE NOT (loadedTime >= '2022-11-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AND loadedTime < '2022-11-08'::timestamp) ;` Please copy paste the exact outputs from your runs.

Comment: And please edit the question and add the CREATE TABLE command or the output of `\d myTable_202211`

Comment: The "row is too big" error suggests you have data corruption.